# Allow Gravity Form users to login and Edit their own entries front end

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a form using GravityForm here http://magicsoft.us/appathon/registration in the wordpress site.

After a user submit an entry an account will be automatically created. I need users to login with their username and password submitted through form and Can Update the form data they submitted.

How can i do this? I tried with Gravity View but it shows other users data also. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> How can i do this? I tried with Gravity View but it shows other users data also. Thanks in advance

Then you didn't have Gravity View set up properly. You need the Advanced Filter add-on for Gravity View and with that installed, you can filter any view to only show entries created by the currently logged in user. I use that feature all of the time and it works great.